# multithreading in adobe flex

Tags: apache-flex, multithreading, flex3, adobe

i want to know if i can use threading model like posix or any else in flex, i am a beginer of flex and i want to know if i can use threads in it for multitasking.

Comment: why would you need threading in Flex, his purpose is to create some client side swf apps that is going to be used by one single user in a browser

Comment: @Omu Threading has nothing to do with a single "user". An example of threading might be if your Flex app is doing something processor intensive but you don't want the user interface to lockup... it allows you to continue the process while the user can do other things. Flash does not have real multi-threading support.

Comment: Many people are asking, why other needs Multithreading in Flex applications. Now I am developing application in Flex Mobile for both Android and Ios systems, so I have a task, where I need to launch background thread, which downloads data from server and saves it to Sqlite db on device. Asynchronous model provided by Adobe suggests ugly solution, where I need to provide callback function on each DB operation. I have experience of solving such a tasks in Android SDK with multithreads and it is much more elegant and understandable.

Answer (score 1):

No, your Flash/Flex code will only run on a single thread, but you can achieve a lot through the asynchronous/event model.

Answer (score 0):

Flex and ActionScript are single-threaded, so there's no threading model you can use.

Answer (score 0):

http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Is_multi_threading_possible_in_Flash_or_ActionScri-12026.html

this is official from adobe

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concept of [Green Threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads) to provide multi threading in your Flex app.

Check this [link](http://blog.generalrelativity.org/actionscript-30/green-threads/) for a sample implementation of Green Threads.

You would basically have to split your processing into chunks and use the main thread to run your thread along with your normal app.